# Condition for a polynomial-like function to map from real to (a subset) of real

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

For a polynomial $p(z)$, where its coefficients are complex, what is the necessary & sufficient condition that satisfy $p(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$? My guess is that it should have real coefficients, but I did not find a way to rigorously prove that result.

Meanwhile, the problem also have 2 alternative versions:

(1) $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ for $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ with $p$ and $q$ being polynomials.

(2) $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ for $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ a Taylor series.

My thought are that they still need to have real coefficients (after cancelling some common factors for the fraction case) for these 2 alternatives. Am I right? Also, how should I prove that the claim is indeed necessary & sufficient rigorously?

Comment: For your original problem and (2), consider $f(z) - \overline{f(\overline z)}$.  It isn't clear what you are asking for (1).